# My lists are adding up incorrectly

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, stack

So far I have been asking a lot of questions about this same code, but this is definitely the last error and all I ask for this time is guidance and to see if I'm on the right track to fixing it. I will show the output I get below:

[image]

And again I will show the output iI'm expecting to receive

[image]

Now what I think is happening, when s2 is set to 0, I believe that the `s1 = s1 + s2` part isn't recognizing that s2 is empty because it starts with 0? But overall, the s2 stack is not empty when it should be, I don't really understand how this can be when it was just set to NULL.

I will show the function that adds my lists together:

```
Stack operator+(const Stack& s) const
    {
        // copy the first list
        Stack t = *this;
        Stack u = *this;
        Node *n = s.top;

        // iterate through the second list and copy each element to the new list
        while (n != NULL && !t.IsFull())
        {
            t.Push(n->data);
            n = n->link;
        }
        n = t.top;
        while(n != NULL && !t.IsEmpty())
        {
            u.Push(n->data);
            t.Pop();
            n = t.top;
        }

        return u;
    }
```

In the above code I tried returning t instead and that resulted in `*s1 = s1 + s2` being NULL, so I believe the problem may be somewhere in this code or in previous code, I will also show my `operator=` function below:

```
void operator=(const Stack& s)
    {
        if (s.top == NULL){
            num_items = 0;
            top = NULL;}
        else
        {
            top = new Node;
            top->data = s.top->data;
            Node* newP = top;
                num_items = 1;
                for(Node* curr = s.top->link; curr != NULL; curr = curr->link)

                {
                    if(num_items != MAX_SIZE)
                    {
                    newP->link = new Node;
                    newP = newP->link;
                    newP->data = curr->data;
                    ++num_items;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Edit: I posted the entire program below in hopes that it would make the problem clear

http://ideone.com/KaJWFQ

Comment: `operator=` should not be returning `void`.

Comment: @chris the problem is that it absolutely has to, that's the function we're required to use.

Comment: You have asked enough questions to know what a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org) is. You're asking us to do a lot of extra work to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Beta i apologize i will post so the outcome can be seen better

Comment: @Beta http://ideone.com/KaJWFQ, i hope that helps in showing the error clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in `s2`, the problem is in `operator+`. Let's put some `cout` statements in the operator, to see what's going on:

```
Stack operator+(const Stack& s) const
{
  // copy the first list
  Stack t = *this;
  Stack u = *this;
  Node *n = s.top;

  // iterate through the second list and copy each element to the new list
  while (n != NULL && !t.IsFull())
  {
    t.Push(n->data);
    n = n->link;
  }

  cout << "end of first while loop, t is " << t << endl;

  cout << "entering second while loop, u is " << u << endl;

  n = t.top;
  while(n != NULL && !t.IsEmpty())
  {
    u.Push(n->data);
    t.Pop();
    n = t.top;
  }

  cout << "end of second while loop, u is " << u << endl;

  return u;
}
```

Suppose `*this` is {1 2 3} and `s` is {4 5 6}. One might hope `that adding them would result in {1 2 3 4 5 6}, but the result of the exercise is:

```
end of first while loop, t is 6 5 4 1 2 3
entering second while loop, u is 1 2 3 
end of second while loop, u is 3 2 1 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

At the end of the first loop, all of the elements are in t, but in the wrong order, and it's not clear how to rearrange them. At the end of the second loop, things have clearly gone off the rails.

Comment: Thank you, that does clear things up a lot for me, what i assume is that my push and pop methods are coded incorrectly, i can't think of any other thing that would give an outrageous output

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux: Then *test* your push and pop methods. Test them before you try to build on them. Every good developer knows this, but I have yet to hear of a professor who teaches it. And the output above is perfectly logical, if you know what those methods actually do.